# Insert dynamically generated form inputs to MySQL database using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a form for adding cheques to a system. The form has two parts; part one is for the common info i.e the customer details and part two is for the unique details i.e cheque details. Multiple cheques can be added for the same user by clicking an Add button which generates duplicate inputs for the form.
While saving the data on mysql database using Laravel, i got the error

> "Undefined offset: 1"

Here is my laravel controller :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $customer_name = $request->customer_name;
  $cheque_number=$request->cheque_number;
  $count = count($cheque_number);

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
        $objModel = new Cheque();
        $objModel->customer_name = $customer_name[$i];
        $objModel->cheque_number = $cheque_number[$i];
        $objModel->save();
    }
}
```

My main challenge is each cheque number should be saved on a new row, but with the same customer name which is provided only once.

Comment: customer name contain single value or mulitple ?

Comment: the customer name is a single value while the cheque number can have more than one value. different cheque numbers should be stored in different db rows but with the same customer name

Comment: Can you show your form that sent data to controller ?

Comment: @Shibon No. That looks like a different question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036183/array-check-undefined-offset-php/43036264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $customer_name = $request->customer_name;
  $cheque_number = $request->cheque_number;
  $count = count($cheque_number);

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
       if(isset($cheque_number[$i])) {  //for check value is set or not..
          $objModel = new Cheque();
          $objModel->customer_name = $customer_name;  //same name
          $objModel->cheque_number = $cheque_number[$i]; //different number
          $objModel->save();  
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function store(Request $request){
 $customer_name = $request->get('customer_name');
 $cheque_number = $request->get('cheque_number');
 $count = count($cheque_number);

 for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
  if(isset($cheque_number[$i])){
   $objModel = new Cheque();
          $objModel->customer_name = $customer_name;  //same name
          $objModel->cheque_number = $cheque_number[$i]; //different number
          $objModel->save(); 
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $customer_name = $request->customer_name;
  $cheque_number = $request->cheque_number;
  $count = count($cheque_number);

    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
       if(isset($cheque_number[$i])) {  
          $objModel = new Cheque();
          $objModel->customer_name = $customer_name;  //same name
          $objModel->cheque_number = $cheque_number[$i]; //different number
          $objModel->save();  
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Vic: Glad to help :)